# how to get IP from DHCP in network in redhat which is installed on VMware

Tags: rhel, dhcp, vmware

I'm running Red Hat inside a VMware image (on a Windows XP machine). I want to connect the Red Hat VM to our network; do I need to configure something inside VMware or inside Red Hat? I don't have any IPs set to connect to the internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that you have a DHCP server set up on your internal network, all you should need to do is to **configure the VMware virtual NIC to be in bridged mode**; this tells VMWare to act as a virtual bridge with respect to any packets the virtual machine sends out. When I say a vitrual bridge, I mean a device that just crosses the border between virtual and physical.

Comment: I installed an ubuntu9 on VM, and it worked. unfortunately I don't have access on redhat 4.7

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat is the name of a company, the last distribution called just Redhat Linux was 9.0 in 2003. Therefore I guess you are in fact running Redhat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).

If you run a recent version, i.e. RHEL 5.x, the network connections are configured using a program called system-config-network. Normally, VMware should give the Linux system network access by means of a virtual network card out of the box, so the process should be self-explaining.

If you need a guide, you can follow generic instructions for getting networking running on RHEL. See, e.g., http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedoracore-linux-network-card-configuration/